# JSch for pbrun not working

Tags: jsch

I tried to execute pbrun using JSch. But it gets into infinite loop. I tried the same program using the JSch site examples to execute the command. I even tried session.setPty(true) before session. connect(). Still, its not working. Please help.

Comment: Show us your code. What do you mean by an infinite loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution by my own research. We can use pbrun with -c option so that we launch pbrun and get the command output in one shot. In my case, i have passwordless connectivity. So It is like **pbrun su - username -c 'command'**

Comment: How to execute multiple commands after "pbrun su -"? It doesn't enter in new shell.

Comment: pbrun su - myjobs -c 'cd /apps/myapp/loader/error ;cp cd /apps/myapp/loader/error/error/one.txt /users/myuserid/one.txt;ls -lrt     is there any way to add the multiple command after pbrun su ?

Comment: after pbrun , i have to move to particular directory and copy the files  . is there any way to do in JSCH ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I read about `pbrun`, it seems like it starts a new shell (similarly to `su`).

So if by *"inifinite loop"* you mean that `pbrun` never finishes, it is (might be) correct. It never finishes, the same way `su` never finishes (until you issue an `exit` command).

Comment: I agree with you Martin. But after issuing pbrun, when I ssue another command, I'm not getting any output. Regarding code, same code as in jcraft site. That's why I didn't copy pasted. Here is the link http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html

Comment: Can you show us the code anyway? We need to see how you issue the another commands and your commands syntax.